# Difference between Mexican Spanish and Spanish?

Tags: méxico, español-neutral

What are the main difference between South American Spanish and Spanish ?

Comment: Hi welcome to the site. You have to be more specific on the questions you ask. Are you asking Mexican spanish or South American spanish? I am putting your question on hold until you resolve these issues. Consult the [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help) for more info about how to ask a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-main-differences-between-spanish-in-spain-and-spanish-in-latin-amer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las principales diferencias están en el uso de algunos verbos y de algunas palabras. Por ejemplo coger, tortitas, ...

En la siguientes páginas hay más información.
En la primera página la información hace referencia a la cultura, uso de verbos... en la segunda a la pronunciación.

http://desmadreando.com/2014/05/06/diferencias-culturales/

http://lalenguaespanolaenelmundo.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/las-diferencias-entre-el-espanol-de.html

Comment: Should also note the barbaric influences in structure and lexical forms http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=barbarismo